# ternary operator in matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

is there a way of typing for if like:

```
var = (cond) ? true : false;
```

or do we have to use this format?

```
if (cond)
 true
else
 false
end
```

Comment: But for a more general case, see some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561881/one-liner-for-if-true-then-a-else-b-in-matlab/27562100#27562100

Answer (score 40):

MatLab doesn't have a ternary operator, or any other syntactic sugar for one-line if-statements. But if your if-statement is really simple, you could just write it in one line anyway:

```
if (cond); casetrue(); else; casefalse(); end
```

It's not as simple as ternary operator, but still better than writing it in 5 lines of code.

Comment: Hoever simple, if/switch/loop statements aren't supported in lambda/anonymous function definitions in Matlab.

Answer (score 20):

Hmm... no one has mentioned this

```
fi = @(varargin)varargin{end-varargin{1}}
```

somewhere in the docs it is written the `end' is coming to one so this will be more future proof

```
fi = @(varargin)varargin{length(varargin)-varargin{1}}
```

Usage :

```
fi(input('Do you like Matlab ? '),'yes','no')
>> no
```

If your in the need of inline cases see [Mathworks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/#c8d04efb-1a2d-4c35-afff-dd52e6c660d2) ...

Comment: This is probably the ugliest and hardest to understand piece of Matlab code I've seen. Usage is easy though, yay!

Comment: Note that, unlike an `if`, both sides are evaluated.

Also, this assumes that your first argument is logical (aka Boolean). Whereas an `if` will consider `3` to be `true`, this method will see `3` as `false`. You can simulate [how `if` works](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) using `fi = @(varargin) varargin{length(varargin) - logical(varargin{1})};`. If your input is a matrix, you can use `fi = @(varargin) varargin{length(varargin) - all(logical(varargin{1}), "all")};`.

Answer (score 13):

If you only need true or false, you can do what `MatlabSorter` suggests. In case you want a real tertiary operator (i.e. `a = b ? c : d`), there is none in MATLAB. However, using the file supplied [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18800-almost-a-ternary-conditional-operator), you can get close.

Answer (score 12):

You can do

```
var = 5 > 4;
```

which will set var to true. Just substitute what ever you need for 5 > 4.

Comment: Na, you can use (a > b) as a factor and then add another product with the opposite statement : `var = (a < 0) * (-a) + (a >= 0) * (a)`

Comment: If we need to use the ternary operator inside disp or fprintf?

Answer (score 10):

MATLAB doesn't have conditional expressions, but in some situations you can get a similar effect by saying, e.g., `var = cond*true_expr + (1-cond)*false_expr`. Unlike C's conditional expression, this will of course always evaluate both `true_expr` and `false_expr`, and if `cond` happens not to be either 0 or 1 (note: `false` behaves like 0; `true` behaves like 1) you'll get crazy results.

Comment: It should be possible to create a function which takes a condition and two function handles. Then you have the wanted shortcut behaviour.

Comment: Elegant but works only for numerical expressions, I tried it with strings and it returned them as an ASCII values array

Comment: This also does not work if `true_expr` or `false_expr` are `inf`

Answer (score 6):

The following solution has *two major advantages* over the solutions proposed so far:

1. It supports **lazy evaluation**, i.e. only the selected input is evaluated.
2. Unlike a `if`/`else` statement packed in one line, it **can also be used in anonymous functions**.

```
function out = tern(cond, resTrue, resFalse)

if cond
    res = resTrue;
else
    res = resFalse;
end 
out = res();  %<--- The trick!
```

The trick to achieve lazy evaluation is that the last line in `tern` evaluates the selected result. This way, you can pass anonymous functions to `tern` and only the selected will be invoked.

E.g. the following can be invoked without error, when the file with `fileName` is not existing:

```
x = tern( isfile( fileName), @()load( fileName ), ones(10 ));
```

It should be noted that, when `res` is not a anonymous function but of a different basic type (e.g. numeric, character, cell ) in the last line, `res()` evaluates to `res` itself.

So in summary, the only little difference to a *real* ternary operator is that it is required to add `@()` to the arguments that should only be conditionally evaluated.

Comment: shouldn't the third parameter be "@()ones(10)" ?

Comment: This is also an option to save execution time for "ones(10)". However, it would not fail with "ones(10)".

Comment: Great hack, I'd not realize `ones(10)` simply works without having to check it's a lambda

Answer (score 4):

Quick and elegant. I would simply write tern( a>b, a, b)
Downside is you have to copy paste everywhere, or have and extra file in the directory

```
function b = tern(cond, a, b)
    if cond
        b=a;
    end
end
```

Comment: beware that this does not work if you need lazy evaluation, e.g. `b` always evaluates regardless of `cond` (might seem obvious, but you probably just think abstract: 'Ah ternary operator here we go' and use it as normal, things might break for you)...

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
c = (x ? a : b)
```

by

```
c = subsref({b; a}, substruct('{}', {x + 1}))
```

x should be a boolean value or 1 or 0.
true or 1 will select a
false or 0 will select b
This should work with all what cells can contain and can also be used in an intricate formular!

Comment: Note: a and b are both evaluated. This may be a difference to if ... else ... end.

Answer (score 3):

@Leonid Beschastny is correct about the inlining the `if-else-end` statement, but If one must, then with any assignment value that can be evaluated as boolean, one can the shortcut boolean operators `||` and `&&`:

```
(cond) && ((var=true_val)||1) || (var=false_val);
```

Rules:

1. shortcut boolean ops `||` and `&&` must be used, **NOT** `|` or `&`
2. will work with boolean, numeric and char assignments
3. will **NOT** work with cell array or function handles
4. the assignments must be wrapped in parenthesis.
5. `(var=true_val)` must be followed by `||1` in case `true_val == false`
6. **true** and **false** assignments may be to different variables    (i.e. `(var1=true_val)` while `(var2=false_val)`)
7. `true_val` and `false_val` can be different types provided each then can be evaluated as boolean

Alternatively one can do this:

```
cond && (func1(..)||1) || func2(...);
```

provided `func1` and `func2` return a boolean testable value including nothing at all (but no cell arrays!):

Comment: For which Matlab version is this? I have R2018a and the assignment var=true_val does not work. Matlab reports a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

I use this style frequently:

```
cond = what < ever;

n = getfield([23,42], {1+(what < ever)}) % for any 1x1-data
s = cell2mat(getfield({'no','yes'}, {1+(what < ever)})) % for nonuniform
```

it's compact enough to not require a helper function

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but for people trying to find an answer I came up with this.

If you want a **boolean** `var = (cond) ? true : false;`
you can just do:

```
var = cond;
```

If you want a **number** `var = (cond) ? value_if_true: value_if_false;`
then do:

```
var = cond*value_if_true + ~cond*value_if_false;
```

This is all using that matlab treats true as 1 and false as 0.
Therefore that's why the first statement expanded really is

```
var = cond*1+ ~cond*0;
```

If you want a **text** `var = (cond) ? text_if_true: text_if_false;`
then do:

```
[repmat(text_if_true,1,cond) repmat(text_if_false,1,~cond)];
```

Unfortunately you can't mix numerical values with text using this method, just write it with an if-else-end statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when I needed to set my matrix values to `0` or `1` based on an arbitrary condition (e.g. element value is greater than `pi`). Turns out it's as easy as:

```
M > pi
```

Sure it's less generic than the original question but this corner case may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a vectorized ternary (operating on logical arrays and number arrays), here's a really simple one (it is not short-circuiting):

```matlab
vectorizedTernary = @(cond, resTrue, resFalse) cond.*resTrue + (1-cond).*resFalse
```

```matlab
vectorizedTernary([0 1 1 0 0], 1:5, 5:-1:1) % ans = [5 2 3 2 1]
```

Because I used `1-cond` instead of `~cond`, you can even use it with non-logical conditions, like probabilities:

```matlab
vectorizedTernary([.2 .7 1], [.1 .2 .3], [0 1/3 2/3]) % ans = [.02 .24 .3]
```