# Matlab conditional assignment

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for Matlab equivalent of c# `condition ? true-expression : false-expression` conditional assignment. The most I know of is `a = 5>2`, which is true\false assignment, 
but is there any one line conditional assignment for
`if condition a=1;else  a=2; end`?

Comment: Awfully close to being a duplicate of this: [if-statement in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5594937/52738) You may find some of the answers there helpful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One line conditional assignment:

```
a(a > 5) = 2;
```

This is an example of logical indexing, `a > 5` is a logical (i.e. Boolean or binary) matrix/array the same size as `a` with a `1` where ever the expression was true.  The left side of the above assignment refers to all the positions in `a` where `a>5` has a `1`.

```
b = a > 5; % if a = [9,3,5,6], b = [1,0,0,1]
a(~b) = 3;
c = a > 10;
a(b&c) = ...
```

Etc...you can do pretty much anything you'd expect with such logical arrays.

Comment: is it possible to put in an else? - to assign something in both cases? Like: a (b&c) = 1 : 0;

Comment: @skofgar The only way to that is with two lines: `a(b&c) = 1;` and `a(b~=c) = 0;` or `a(xor(b,c)) = 0`.

Comment: Wait, I'm stupid. What is the value of `b` after `b = a > 5;`?

Comment: An array of logical (boolean) values, with each element holding the output of the conditional for the corresponding element in `a`. Think of it as a binary 'mask'  over `a` indicating where `a` contains a value greater than 5. Updated with a little comment.

Comment: What does it say? Assign `2` to `a` if condition is true, else do nothing?

Answer (score 24):

For numeric arrays, there is another solution --

```
// C: 
A = COND ? X : Y;
```

becomes

```
% MATLAB
% A, X and Y are numerics 
% COND is a logical condition.

A = COND.*X + (~COND).*Y ;
```

**Advantage:**

works wonderfully in parallel for vectors or large arrays - each item in `A` gets assigned depending on the corresponding condition. The same line works for:

- condition is scalar, arrays `X` and `Y` are equal in size
- condition is an array of any size, X and Y are scalars
- condition and X and Y are all arrays of the same size

**Warning:**

Doesn't work gracefully with `NaN`s. Beware! If an element of `X` is `nan`, or an element of `Y` is nan, then you'll get a `NaN` in `A`, irrespective of the condition.

**Really Useful corollary:**

you can use `bsxfun` where `COND` and `X`/`Y` have different sizes.

```
A = bsxfun( @times, COND', X ) +  bsxfun( @times, ~COND', Y );
```

works for example where `COND` and `X`/`Y` are vectors of different lengths.

neat eh?

Answer (score 21):

Matlab does not have a ternary operator. You though easily write a function that will do such thing for you:

```
function c = conditional(condition , a , b)
    if condition
        c = a;
    else
        c = b;
    end
end
```