# how to convert this expression to a MATLAB code

Tags: matlab

I am new to programming and i start with Matlab. How to convert this expression to a MATLAB code :

```
a = if !IsNaN(x) then b else Double.NaN;
```

Comment: Are you stuck on the ternary part? [It looks like Matlab doesn't have that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594937/ternary-operator-in-matlab): you may have to split this out into the NaN check on x and two separate assignments of a. Or are you stuck on something else?

Comment: @Rup : I stuck on NaN and Double.NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "not" functionality of "!" is implemented by "~" in MATLAB.

So, your code would look something like

```
if ~isnan(x)
   a = b
else 
   a = NaN;
end
```